# Retrieving email string using regex

Tags: regex

So I am looking to extract a set of characters from unique reset verification codes that I get in my emails. Meaning, what im trying to extract will be different every time. This is the example:

"You requested one-time code for authentication.

Your code is 7a8c28

Enter the code to verify your login."

I am trying to extract the "7a8c28" (without the quotation marks).

This is the regex expression I have written because I am trying to remove the whitespace after the "is":
[^is_\s*]*$

However, that expression above spits out a single period, and not the 7a8c28. 
Am i missing something here? Or is there a better expression to use? Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: [`is (.+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/VN410H/1) would put `7a8c28` into group #1 for you.

Comment: Or you can just add a word boundary to your existing regex: `[^is_\s*]*\b$`

Comment: Which is the language?

Answer (score 0):

\sis\s(\w+)\b
captures the code as captured group 1 ($1).

Answer (score 0):

```
\bis\h*(\S+)$
```

will capture in group 1 the value you're searching for.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/0dMeIJ/1)